# How I can connect a bridge but use the wifi of the router?

Tags: bridge, wireless-bridge, bridge-router

I'm not very familiar with networks, but I'm curious if this can be possible...

Let me explain the context of the network:

The hardware that I have is the modem-router of the ISP (IMR), and a TP-link WR740n (modem-router too). 
The IMR is used as a modem, and the WR740n is used as a bridge. They are connected by an ethernet cable. IMR(eth port 0) <---> WR740n(WAN port). So all wifi connections are managed by the WR740n router. The thing is that IMR has a better wifi range than WR740n. WR740n has bandwidth control **enabled**, **IMR doesn't have bandwidth control feature**. The bridge has about 6-15 active users, network only for a house.

The question is:

**Is there a way to use IMR as a modem, then use WR740n as a bridge (to use bandwidth control) but all wifi connections were managed by IMR?**

Thanks in advance guys. I'm a novice on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible :
All direct connections to the IMR will bypass totally the WR740n.

The WR740n can only manage connections and traffic that passes through it
from connected devices. It cannot do bandwidth control for traffic that
doesn't pass through it.

For what you want, the IMR will need to pass its direct traffic through the WR740n,
sending and receiving it back in a loop. The firmware of the IMR (or any other
router/modem) is just not built for it.

Comment: Thank you for your knowledge. I really don't understand 100% how a router-modem works, so that's why im asking haha